# Dell XPS L502x cannot boot Ubuntu after successful installation

Tags: boot, 22.04

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from official website and used Rufus to create a bootable disk (MBR). I used this flash disk to boot on Dell XPS L502x and install ubuntu with default settings. It partitioned my entire SSD disk with default settings. The installation completed successfully. After restarting, there is no operating system. The message is saying `OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND`. I could not find a proper answer for this problem in my old laptop.

Comment: @karel I tested GPT. It could not boot on flash.

Comment: My 2006 laptop boots with gpt in old BIOS mode. Yours is somewhat early UEFI and UEFI highly suggests gpt partitioning. Microsoft required systems to be UEFI with gpt partitioning starting in 2012 with release of Windows 8. Make sure system is set to boot in same mode as you installed. How you boot install media UEFI or old BIOS/CSM/legacy is then how it installs & must be default boot mode of installed system. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. Error typical of UEFI boot mode not matching installed mode.

Comment: @oldfred There is no settings on bios for changing UEFI mode.

Comment: If it is before UEFI, then limited system and full Ubuntu will not work. Use a lightweight flavor to install in old BIOS mode. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie